# Do antiferromagnets have hysteresis loops?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I am aware that ferromagnets have hysteresis loops and their shape depend on the relative size of magnetic interaction energy to thermal energy. I doubt if there is something equivalent to the hysteresis loop for antiferromagnets? Further to my question, how about paramagnets?